# Predict projectile path with different walls and distance on third person

Tags: unreal-engine4

Main problem: I want to predict projectile path based on Crosshair Center or Camera Center

https://imgur.com/a/ymlWxt1

**Trace Line**

> From Camera Center towards Camera Forward Vector * Distance

So in this Screenshot 1 I have predicted projectile path while using Impact Point of the Trace Line.

So the thing is. If I move my camera a little upper then projectile path would change and it's gonna be pointed to the Trace Line Impact Point of the wall that far away like in Screenshot 2.

But as you can see by the logic of gravity you can assume that if you move camera a little upper that projectile path should pointed to the wall at Point B. How can I do this? Maybe I shouldn't even do Trace Line to detect impact points but maybe there are some other tricks in third person view?

```
void UBowComponent::CharacterTraceLine(UWorld* const World, double Distance, bool DrawTrace, FHitResult& HitResult)
{
    const auto* Camera = Character->GetFollowCamera();
    const FVector TraceStartLocation = Camera->GetComponentLocation();

    const FVector CameraForwardVector = Camera->GetForwardVector();
    const FVector TraceEndLocation = TraceStartLocation + CameraForwardVector * Distance;
    
    FCollisionQueryParams CollisionQueryParams;
    CollisionQueryParams.AddIgnoredActor(Character);

    if(DrawTrace)
    {
        FName TraceTag = FName(TEXT("CharacterTraceTag"));
        CollisionQueryParams.TraceTag = TraceTag;
        World->DebugDrawTraceTag = TraceTag;
    }
    
    World->LineTraceSingleByChannel(HitResult, TraceStartLocation, TraceEndLocation, ECC_Visibility, CollisionQueryParams);
    ImpactPoint = HitResult.bBlockingHit ? HitResult.ImpactPoint : TraceEndLocation;
}

FTransform UBowComponent::CalculateArrowTransform()
{
    FTransform Transform = GetSocketTransform(TEXT("arrow_socket"));
    Transform.SetScale3D(FVector::One());
    Transform.SetRotation(UKismetMathLibrary::MakeRotFromX(ImpactPoint - Transform.GetLocation()).Quaternion());

    return Transform;
}

void UBowComponent::PredictArrowPath(UWorld* const World, FPredictProjectilePathResult& ProjectilePathResult)
{
    FHitResult TraceLineHitResult;
    CharacterTraceLine(World, 15000.0, false, TraceLineHitResult);
    
    FTransform SpawnTransform   = CalculateArrowTransform();
    FVector SpawnLocation       = SpawnTransform.GetLocation();
    FRotator SpawnRotation      = SpawnTransform.Rotator();

    FPredictProjectilePathParams ProjectilePathParams = FPredictProjectilePathParams(
        2.f
        , SpawnLocation
        , SpawnRotation.Vector() * PowerScale,
        10.f
        , ECC_WorldStatic, GetOwner());
    ProjectilePathParams.DrawDebugType = EDrawDebugTrace::Type::ForDuration;
    ProjectilePathParams.DrawDebugTime = 0.f;
    ProjectilePathParams.SimFrequency = 30.f;
    ProjectilePathParams.bTraceComplex = false;
    ProjectilePathParams.OverrideGravityZ = -980 * GravityScaleZ;

    UGameplayStatics::PredictProjectilePath(GetWorld(), ProjectilePathParams, ProjectilePathResult);
}
```